# Logstash UDP issue

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have simple logstash config where I am routing(shipping) logs to secondary logstash based on the beat host name, below is the primary/secondary logstash config. I masked the IP here, but primary logstash is not shipping any logs to the secondary.

```
1) Is it the if condition needs to have [host] or [agent][hostname] in primary logstash?
2) On secondary do I need to receive for UDP or TCP ?
```

I tried to check netstat o/p on primary and secondary. Its not showing the any results on the primary node where as showing at the secondary node.

`sudo netstat -ulpat | grep 8011`

My main logstash config

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["http://<ip1>:9200","http://<ip2>:9200","http://<ip3>:9200"]
    }
  }
#  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
output {
  if [host] =~ "moaf-iws" {
    udp {
      host => "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
      port => "8011"
    }
  }
}
```

Secondary log stash

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

input {
  udp {
         port => 8011
      }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["http://<ip1>:9200","http://<ip2>:9200"]
    }
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

Comment: run logstash pipeline with `--debug` flag and post results

Comment: What is your Logstash and Beats version? Do you have a `host` field? Since Filebeat version 6.3 the `host` field is a json object, the hostname is in the field `host.name`. Run the output with the stdout and see in which field do you have the hostname.

Comment: @leandrojmp - Beats version is 7.2 and when I ran stdout I'm able to see only agent hostname only.

Comment: You should use the field agent.hostname in your output conditional then, just change your if to `if [agent][hostname] =~ "moaf-iws"`